# How to Understand the Opposite Functor?

Tags: category-theory

Given $F: C \rightarrow D$, suppose one wants to define the opposite functor $F^{op} : C^{op} \rightarrow D^{op}$, as mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor#Opposite_functor). My question is about how we define this functor. If $x \rightarrow^f y$ in C, $F$ takes this to $Fx \rightarrow^{Ff} Fy$ in $D$. Then, is it that:

a) $F^{op}$ flips arrows in both categories. So, it takes $x \rightarrow^f y$ in $C$ to $y \rightarrow x$ in $C^{op}$, and $Fx \rightarrow^{Ff} Fy$ to $Fy \rightarrow^{Ff} Fx$ in $D^{op}$. But in this case, $F^{op}$ does not map morphisms identically to $F$, which would take the same arrow in $C$ to $Fx \rightarrow^{Ff} Fy$.

b) So, say $F^{op}$ takes $x \rightarrow^f y$ in $C$ to $Fx \rightarrow^{Ff} Fy$ in $D^{op}$. That is, it maps identically to $F$. But then, since $F$ maps to the category $D$, it must be that $F$ maps to $Fy \rightarrow^{Ff} Fx$, which is contradictory.

What is the right way to think about the opposite functor?

Comment: Hi again. I used `\newcommand{\op}{^{\mathsf{op}}}` to get, e.g., `F\op` rendered easily as $F^{\mathsf{op}}$, for reference if you want to format things. Also, I recommend `x\overset{f}{\longrightarrow}y` for better formatting of the arrows.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I’ll start using these notations

Comment: You can also write `x \xrightarrow{f} y` to get $x \xrightarrow{f} y$. That way the arrow will stretch, e.g. $x\xrightarrow{\text{long expression}}y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\op}{^{\mathsf{op}}}$Regarding a), $F\op$ cannot “flip arrows in both categories” since $F\op$ has $C\op$ as its domain: it can’t take an input from $C\op$, say: “no, I’d rather have it the other way round, thank you”, and then map into $D\op$ (I hope I correctly interpreted what you meant). After all, $F\op$ is a functor and a functor must preserve the direction of arrows from the domain to the codomain. But, $C\op$ *is already flipped*. If $x\overset{f}{\longrightarrow}y$ in $C$, then $y\overset{f}{\longrightarrow}x$ in $C\op$, and $F\op$ maps this arrow to $Fy\overset{Ff}{\longrightarrow}Fx$ in $D\op$, so this finally corresponds to $Fx\overset{Ff}{\longrightarrow}Fy$ in $D$.

As for b), you made the same mistake, really: $F\op$ only ever accepts input from $C\op$, so there’d be no contradiction as, if $x\to y$ in $C\op$, then $y\to x$ in $C$.

As for “the right way to think about it”, my personal take (not as a category theory expert, mind you) is that, really, $C$ and $C\op$ are not so very different. All $F\op$ is doing is preserving $F$ through this “duality” transformation, from the land of $C$ to the land of $C\op$ (to be slightly whimsical), and is encoding essentially the same thing.

Comment: I guess it didn’t come across as what I intended it to, but in (1) I was trying to say that $F^{op}$ maps flipped arrows of $C$ to flipped arrows of $D$ - which is what you also seem to be saying (right?). That is, for morphisms $f: x \rightarrow y$ in $C$, $F^{op}$ takes it to $Ff: Fy \rightarrow Fx$ in $D^{op}$, which is identically $Ff: Fx \rightarrow Fy$ in $D$?

Comment: @AryanDugar Yes that’s right, although for formality’s sake, and also for the sake of not getting confused when dealing with other situations, $F^{\mathsf{op}}$ doesn’t take arrows in $C$, but it takes their duals in $C^{\mathsf{op}}$. That perspective helps make the functoriality clear. Unfortunately, there is a notion of a *co*variant and *contra*variant functor, which both seemingly act on the same category $C$, but actually the former acts on $C$ and the latter acts on $C^{\mathsf{op}}$!